# Is there a way to find a Zombie Azure Storage?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage

I found if I delete an Azure function, the linked Azure Storage won't be deleted. And it is difficult to find which Azure Storage is Zombie unless to check logs one by one in Azure log.

Is there any easy way to find Zombie Azure Storage?

Here Zombie is something like [Zombie process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Answer (score 0):

If the function app deployment was done through (Powershell script, Terraform, ARM Templates) you can pull the storage account details of the particular function using the deployment name.

If the function app deployment was done through portal you need to manually check the associated details using Activity logs only.